# how to change scalability in xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, scale, screen-resolution, android-calendar

This is my app in screen size 5.0, and 4.0.How can I change scales in the same way everywhere.

5.0

[image]

4.0

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sprawdz"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Wybierz dzień"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_celen">

        <CalendarView

            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="537dp">

        </CalendarView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question. Please read below which i extracted from [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/docs)

> To ensure that your layout is flexible and adapts to different screen
>   sizes, you should use "wrap_content" and "match_parent" for the width
>   and height of most view components, instead of hard-coded sizes.
>
> "wrap_content" tells the view to set its size to whatever is necessary
>   to fit the content within that view.
>
> "match_parent" makes the view expand to as much as possible within the
>   parent view.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
> ```
>
> Although the actual layout for this view depends on other attributes
>   in its parent view and any sibling views, this TextView intends to set
>   its width to fill all available space (match_parent) and set its
>   height to exactly as much space is required by the length of the text
>   (wrap_content). This allows the view to adapt to different screen
>   sizes and different lengths of text.

And  further more you can use different layouts for different screen sizes as described below.

> You can provide screen-specific layouts by creating additional
>   res/layout/ directories—one for each screen configuration that
>   requires a different layout—and then append a screen configuration
>   qualifier to the layout directory name (such as layout-w600dp for
>   screens that have 600dp of available width).
>
> These configuration qualifiers represent the visible screen space
>   available for your app UI. The system takes into account any system
>   decorations (such as the navigation bar) and window configuration
>   changes (such as when the user enables multi-window mode) when
>   selecting the layout from your app.

```
 res/layout/main_activity.xml # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available Width) 
 res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml # For 7” tablets
 or any screen with 600dp # available width (possibly landscape handsets)
```